# Using Kile's tools in scripts

Tags: kile

I have just started using Kile, and I would like to set up some custom scripts for various things that may help speed up my writing.
One thing I in particular would like to do it make a script that, if executed while the cursor is over the name of a label, gives me a preview of the environment that label sits inside.
So for example, if I want to refer to some theorem, and I am not entirely certain I remember which label to refer to, I can type the label and use this script to quickly check in my bottom panel if that is indeed the correct theorem.

Now, I think I can make the script select the desired part of the text, except that I am not sure if I can do a "find" command in the script. But I have not been able to find a way to make the script execute the preview of the selected area. Is this possible?

Comment: I understand your aim. But, just a question: why you don't use TeXstudio? It has this option. When you move the cursor over the `\ref{xx}` command, you can see a box with the object which has that label.

Comment: @Sigur That might actually be the way to go then. I had a look at both Kile and Texstudio when I decided on an deitor, and I think my choice ended up being based on some fairly arbitrary things. Are there any obvious things Kile can do that Texstudio can't?

Comment: Hum, I don't know about the difference. But you can see this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more-or-less a feature request for Kile.